# Login to Perforce without 2FA popup

Tags: perforce

I would like to login to perforce without Firefox opening a 2FA sign-in. I have set my username using `export P4USER="<my username>"` and my port using  export `P4PORT="<my perforce URL>"`. I have also exported a `P4PASSWD`, even though I believe it is not supported any more.

I have tried...

`p4 login` which opens Firefox popup

`echo $P4PASSWD | p4 login` which opens Firefox popup

`echo $P4PASSWD | p4 -u $P4USER login` which opens Firefox popup

`p4 -u $P4USER -P $P4PASSWD login` which opens Firefox popup

`p4 login2` which prints `Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset` when **not logged in** and `User <user name> does not use multi factor authentication` when **logged in**

`p4 login2 -S list-methods` which prints `Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset` when **not logged in** and `User <user name> does not use multi factor authentication` when **logged in**

`echo $P4PASSWD | p4 login2` which prints `Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset` when **not logged in** and `User <user name> does not use multi factor authentication` when **logged in**

`p4 -u $P4USER -P $P4PASSWD login2` which prints `Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset` when **not logged in** and `User <user name> does not use multi factor authentication` when **logged in**

`echo $P4PASSWD | p4 login2 -S list-methods` which prints `Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset` when **not logged in** and `User <user name> does not use multi factor authentication` when **logged in**

`p4 -u $P4USER -P $P4PASSWD login2 -S list-methods` which prints `Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset` when **not logged in** and `User <user name> does not use multi factor authentication` when **logged in**

I know my username and password are correct. I have quadruple checked.

Am I missing something? These are all of the possible login combinations I could think of. Is this a server configuration problem?

Edit for context:
I use perforce on my machine and the Okta Web GUI is fine, but I want to deploy a script to another machine that users can ssh into and run it. Since it will be over ssh, I can't authenticate through a Web GUI

Comment: How is the 2FA configured?  (Unless this is a new feature I'm unaware of that's turned on by default, I assume there's something configured on the server end that's forcing the client to try to use 2FA, and the details of that configuration might be important -- is it done via an SSO trigger, or an auth trigger, or is there some other mechanism?)

Comment: I'm not sure how its configured right now. I haven't been able to talk to the admin due to the holiday (or figure out who they are). All I know is that p4 opens a web login for 2FA. If I had to guess it was a configuration error when setting up the [three mandatory triggers](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4sag/Content/P4SAG/triggers.second_factor_auth.html). @Samwise

Comment: That seems like a good guess, although it's not clear to me from that documentation that any of those triggers fire on `login`, or that they fire if your user isn't configured for MFA (which according to `login2` it's not).  Are you sure it's not an SSO trigger?  Do you have `P4LOGINSSO` defined on your client?

Comment: It could be an SSO trigger, I'm just not sure of anything to be honest. This is the first I'm hearing about P4LOGINSSO. I did not define it. It seems like is comes undefined on a standard install (echo $P4LOGINSSO shows nothing). I don't see anything about a default file location @Samwise

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what's going on.  The MFA functionality is new to me and what you're describing doesn't match what I'm reading in the documentation -- I don't see how `p4 login` would know to launch Firefox, or how it'd know what URL to open, or why any kind of MFA flow would involve `p4 login` in the first place since according to the doc that's all done through `p4 login2`.  I'd probably try to debug by running `p4 -vrpc=3 login` to see what messages the server is sending to the client and what's being invoked on the client.

Comment: That's illuminating and led me to https://www.perforce.com/manuals/cmdref/Content/CmdRef/P4USEBROWSER.html -- have you tried setting that variable?

Comment: @Samwise. I didn't set it previously. I tried `P4USEBROWSER=false`, then logging-in, firefox still opens.

Comment: Using `p4 -vrpc=3` login I found this section

```Rpc dispatch protocol

RpcRecvBuffer url = https://<preforce_url>/saml/login/01GCC89C8FCEPTPV0Y2K4R83AY

RpcRecvBuffer func = client-OpenUrl

Rpc dispatch client-OpenUrl 

Navigate to URL: https://<perforce_url>/saml/login/01GCC89C8FCEPTPV0Y2K4R83AY```

 Which opens a URL. It seems my admin redirects users to a okta which handles 2fa out of perforce. So my account does not use multi factor authentication. I got all the other errors because the workflow is p4 login & p4 login2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to comments from @Samewise I was able to get some confirmation.

Using `p4 -vrpc=3 login` I found this section

```
Rpc dispatch protocol
RpcRecvBuffer url = https://<perforce_url>/saml/login/01GCC89C8FCEPTPV0Y2K4R83AY
RpcRecvBuffer func = client-OpenUrl
Rpc dispatch client-OpenUrl
Navigate to URL: https://<perforce_url>/saml/login/01GCC89C8FCEPTPV0Y2K4R83AY
```

Note: I replaced my companies actual URL with <perforce_url>

Which opens a URL. It seems my admin redirects users to a Okta sign-in portal which handles 2fa out of perforce. So my account *does not use multi factor authentication*. I got all the other errors because the workflow is `p4 login & p4 login2`, ie you must be already logged-in to run `login2`

Perforce is going to have to be reconfigured for non-interactive log-in to work.

Here are some of the docks I found that provided some extra details.
*[P4 2FA Setup](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4sag/Content/P4SAG/triggers.second_factor_auth.html)
*[ID Provider Configs](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/helix-auth-svc/Content/HAS/example-configs.html)
*[MFA](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4sag/Content/P4SAG/security.mfa.html)
*[login2](https://www.perforce.com/manuals/p4sag/Content/P4SAG/security.mfa.html)

run `p4 help mfa` or `p4 help 2fa` for more information